# subprocess.Popen call a program with parameters

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a EXE file, which could be called like this:

```
Extractor64.exe -F C:\File1 -E  C:\file2
```

When trying to call this from subprocess.Popen, I got an could not find file error:

```
t=subprocess.Popen("start C:\yardi_backup_v2\Extractor64.exe -F C:\yardi_backup_v2\miadmfggp_live_Full_TKDB1A112_201812180000.Lts.bak -E  C:\yardi_backup_v2\tmp\extracted.bak")
t.wait()
```

What is the right structure to call this?

Comment: 1) use raw strings or `\t` becomes tab 2) use parameter _lists_ 3) `start` requires `shell=True`. You probably don't need that with `Popen`

Comment: your last argument is `C:\yardi_backup_v2<TAB>mp\extracted.bak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `start` is a shell built-in. It's not really an executable. So you cannot call it without `shell=True`. That's your primary error: there is no `start.exe` in the system. But there's more...
2. no need to start a process in background since you seem to wait for it. Either start it without `start` and don't wait, or just wait: don't use `start`, so now you can use `check_call` instead.
3. use lists not strings for your arguments.
4. using backslashes within a string needs escaping/raw string prefix, in your case `\t` becomes "TAB char"

my proposal:

```
t=subprocess.check_call([r"C:\yardi_backup_v2\Extractor64.exe",
                         "-F",r"C:\yardi_backup_v2\miadmfggp_live_Full_TKDB1A112_201812180000.Lts.bak",
                         "-E",r"C:\yardi_backup_v2\tmp\extracted.bak"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried run instead of Popen?

```
subprocess.run(['Extractor64.exe', '-F', r'C:\File1','-E' , r'C:\file2'])
```

You can read all about here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

It allows shell=True, etc.